# How Can I Overlay Content on Top of HTML5 Video in Mobile Landscape Mode

Tags: html5-video, ionic4

I'm creating a mobile app using Ionic 4. I want to overlay some text and icons on top of an html 5 video in the app. The overlay is visible using position absolute when the phone is in portrait mode but disappears when the phone is in landscape mode. How can I make the text and icons visible in landscape mode?

Comment: can you share your current code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I figured it out. I just had to prevent the native video player from taking over.